# Arrayformula with different rows? (running total)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to do simple formula `=AS2+AP3` in cell `AS3` for the entire row `AS`. So in cell `AS4` it would be `=AS3+AP4`. I can do it simply with copy and paste. But it doesn't work with `arrayformula`. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a running total of the numbers in column AP, but starting with whatever number is in AS2. You can do this sort of thing with a SUMIF which adds up all the numbers up to the current row:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(AP3:AP="","",sumif(row(AP3:AP),"<="&row(AP3:AP),AP3:AP)+AS2))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. But is that the easiest way to do that sort of thing? Seems complicated. THANK YOU.

Comment: This is the only method I know of that works, because an array formula can't use a previous cell's result in the way that a normal formula copied and pasted can.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. Have a great day.

Comment: Hello Tom. I'm sorry to bother you, but I see that you are very smart and knowledgeable guy. And your answers work and are right on point. I have 2 questions that can't get answered properly. Here are the links [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54777684/averageifs-div-0-solution   and [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774699/array-formula-and-max   .If you have time. I appreciate any help and THANK YOU.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsement! Sorry to disappoint but I don't know a way of doing a running maximum as an array formula only with a regular formula. Will look at the other question as time permits.

Comment: Have had a quick look at the other question, short answer might be to use SUMIFS(...)/COUNTIFS(...), testing for COUNTIFS(...) being zero instead of using AVERAGEIFS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Tom. I was thinking the same thing regarding AVERAFEIFS.

Comment: greetings @TomSharpe I borrowed this formula for some minor calculations in my project and ended up feeding this formula solely on data outputted from QUERY. all went well until I tried to create a one-cell solution when I noticed that last argument from SUMIF is not able to refer directly on data from a query. are you aware by any chance of some magic trick to bypass "not a range error" of 3rd SUMIF argument?

Comment: Sorry @player0 (I'm flattered that you ask my advice) but I don't know how to get round the limitation that the third argument of SUMIF has to be an actual range, which severely limits the places where you can use it.