# Array formula and MAX

Tags: google-sheets, max, array-formulas

I'm trying to get peak/max equity from two columns A & B with an array formula. The reason I use the array formula is because I don't want just `MAX` as an answer in one cell. I want it to update automatically row after row with each new entry without overwriting previous entry. So far I got to this formula, but it gives me the same result in each row.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(AD3:AD="","",MAX("<="&row(AD3:AD),AD3:AD,AB2)))
```

And for clarification I would like it to look something like this:

```
  AB       AD
PEAK     CLOSED
Equity   Equity
 $1195    $1195
 $1195    $1090
 $1285    $1285
 $1285    $1180
 $1315    $1315
 $1315    $1210
 $1315    $1205
```

And now with the above formula ( it's in AB3 ) I get just MAX in each row, starting with row AB3 which is $1315.

It can also just give me MAX for column AD, just so it updates  on each new row and entry. And here's sample sheet.
[sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wv5dzQOBdmB2ZQknUjFhMWvG_vyNX1hsfRIYh_GGTYg/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A>=B2:B, A2:A, B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this just gives me bigger number of the 2 columns in each row. I updated my question with better example and sample doc.