# Averageifs #DIV/0! solution?

Tags: google-sheets, average

I know this question has been asked 100's of times, but...
So I have this formula that gives me `#DIV/0!`.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!L2:L, Sheet1!M2:M, "WIN",Sheet1!E2:E, ">=" &A7, Sheet1!E2:E, "<" &A8)
```

I know I can wrap it around `IFERROR(formula,"")` or `IFERROR(formula,0)` and it works. But there are problems with it in case of real errors with it in the future.

I tried to wrap it around `IF(formula,"")` or `IF(formula,0)`. But it doesn't work, I still get the same `#DIV/0!`.

And how about these, can I use something not to show `0` in the empty cells?

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!M2:M, "WIN",Sheet1!E2:E, ">=" &A7, Sheet1!E2:E, "<" &A8)

=SUMIFS(Sheet1!L2:L, Sheet1!M2:M, "LOSS",Sheet1!E2:E, ">=" &A7, Sheet1!E2:E, "<" &A8)
```

I tried the above `IF(...,"")` and `IF(...,0)` and I either get `#DIV/0!`, `ERROR` or `FALSE`.

**EDIT**

So for clarification I'm working on sheets 2 "[sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wv5dzQOBdmB2ZQknUjFhMWvG_vyNX1hsfRIYh_GGTYg/edit?usp=sharing)" included. This spreadsheet is to keep track of my trades that I will fill out over time. That's why most of sheet 1 is empty at the time. As you can see there's a lot of #DIV?0! on sheet 2. I know I get these because there's no match to most of these on sheet 1. Some of them will get filled out over time, but some of them might not get filled out for a while. As you can see the formulas work with the couple of "test" entries I made on sheet 1 to make sure everything works.

That's why I asked for a better solution then wrapping the formulas in IFERROR(...,""). But if that's the only and best solution then so be it.

[sample doc link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wv5dzQOBdmB2ZQknUjFhMWvG_vyNX1hsfRIYh_GGTYg/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nacho.

I replicated your formula on a Google Sheet. 
It doesn't have a problem with 0 nor empty values. It just doesn't count them.

It **does** have a problem when n*othing matches one of the criteria you specified*.

Then it gives #DIV/0.

[image]

You should check why you're not getting matches in one or more of your criteria.
It could be a range problem with your >= , < conditions.

Good Luck

---

### Edit.

However, I adapted your formula to check if there isn't going to be a match before calulating:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B3:B15;"WIN")=0;"No WIN matches";IF(COUNTIF(B3:B15;">=" &A7)=0;"No >= matches"; IF(COUNTIF(B3:B15;"<" & A8)=0;"No < matches";AVERAGEIFS(E3:E;B3:B;"WIN";D3:D;"<20";C3:C;">10"))))
```

Comment: It's mostly unpopulated worksheet that I'm working on. I mean there's a lot of stuff like all the stats I want to track in the future. But for now most of the cells that I will fill out as time goes by, are empty for now. So yes you're right that the problem is with the matches, because right now there isn't any. And for some of the criteria there might not be any match for a while. So that's why I want to find a solution for that other then IFERROR, so I don't have sheets full of #DIV/0!.  Thank you.

Comment: Great ! I'm glad my approach was useful to you. Sorry I changed the ranges on my answer. I pasted the ones I was using on my sheet. But I'm sure you realised that.

Comment: P.S: if my answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted . It will help others !

Comment: I edited my question with better explanation and sample doc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(
 IF(AND(M:M="WIN",
        ISNUMBER(A7),
        ISNUMBER(a8),
        ISNUMBER(E:E),
        ISNUMBER(L:L)), AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!L2:L, Sheet1!M2:M, "WIN",
                                                Sheet1!E2:E, ">="&A7, 
                                                Sheet1!E2:E, "<"&A8), ),
 "anverageifs error")
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my question with better explanation and sample doc. Thank you.